# Django stuck after runserver

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and am trying to get the server set up.

I have created my project folder (containing manage.py) and after running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it gets stuck after these messages

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
November 11, 2018 - 18:17:53
Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'MyProject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

There is a minute or so pause and then these show up.

```
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
```

After that it just stays there, I cannot type anything or do anything.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to type anything (you just leave it running and Ctrl+C to stop it when you're done)... what is it you expect to be able to do?

Comment: I want to type "python manage.py startapp". Also, what is the reason for the GET lines and why do they appear a lot later?

Comment: Well... either cancel the running server and do it as a separate command, or open another command/shell window and execute it there? "runserver" is not meant to be an interactive prompt... it's just meant to run the development server for you to test your app.

Comment: It says you have 15 unapplied migrations, consider running `python manage.py migrate` before starting the server to install the models into your database for your app to work.

Comment: I see, I feel kind of dumb now for thinking I was supposed to enter things into that window lol.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: The `GET lines` are HTTP GET requests that your django server received, this is the normal behaviour of your server and shows you that it is actually running and working correctly

Comment: It's standard practice to keep runserver running in the forground like this while developing. If you want to run other shell commands, you can open up a new shell session / terminal window. Each time you access your `http://localhost:8000` page with the browser, you should see more of those access logging lines appearing in the runserver terminal session.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The startup time is 5-10 minutes now. Once the first connection is accpeted, everything after that becomes normal.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the behaviour of the `runserver` command, you should use the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine.

Since a server continously listen for connections, it's fine that you don't get the prompt back. If needed, you could use `python manage.py runserver &` to run the server in the background of your shell, or just open another window/tab.

Remember that, to test your website, you have to keep the server open.

Comment: Sounds like someone downvoted all the answers here... Why tho ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't forget the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/) is your friend (even if it's a bit unfriendly).

You are doing everything correctly and the terminal is out putting any requests made to the application:

```
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[11/Nov/2018 18:18:47] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
```

That means you connected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ at the root domain, with which 3 fonts also got sent to the requesting browser/connection.

---

## **What to do now**

I would highly suggest you follow [a simple tutorial like this one](https://www.codementor.io/rogargon/simple-django-web-application-tutorial-du107rmn4), step by step, then follow other tutorials and find what works best for you.

---

## **An alternative idea**

I have tried long and hard to enjoy using Django and for over 6 months I was unhappy working and struggling to get it to work flawlessly. So I found [Flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/) to be a much better alternative and much easier to learn and continue to work with. I recently came across [Quart](https://pypi.org/project/Quart/), which is an asynchronous fork of Flask, and have not looked back since. We can literally build a fully functioning web application shell in a matter of minutes with the help of various Flask extensions.